# how to define server specific jndi on jboss 7.1

Tags: jboss, jndi, jboss7.x

I want to define a jndi object as simple string for each of my servers with in a server group;
I can define a jndi object as a simple string for a profile, and a profile can be attainable to a server-group, so when I define it in this way, all of my servers in this server group would see the same value, however I want to make the value to be different for each of my servers.